# Write a file over network in odoo with authentication

Tags: python, authentication, networking, copy, odoo

I have a Odoo8 running on my linux server and I need to copy a file from this server to a Windows 10 shared folder with authentication.
I tried to do it programmatically like this:

```
full_path = "smb://hostname/shared_folder/other_path"
if not os.path.exists(full_path):
    os.makedirs(full_path)
full_path = os.path.join(full_path, file_name)
bin_value = stream.decode('base64')
if not os.path.exists(full_path):
    try:
        with open(full_path, 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(bin_value)
            fp.close()
        return True
    except IOError:
        _logger.exception("stream_save writing %s", full_path)
```

but even if no exception is raised, folders are not created and file is not written.
Then I tried to remove the "smb:" part from the uri and it raised an exception regarding authentication.

I'd like to fix the problem just by using python, possibly avoiding os.system calls or external scripts, but if no other way is possible, then any suggestion is welcome.

I also tried with

```
"//user:password@hostname"
```

and

```
"//domain;user:password@hostname"
```

both with and without smb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it out by myself a way using SAMBA:

First you need to install pysmb (*pip install pysmb*) then:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
conn = SMBConnection(user, password, "my_name", server, domain=domain, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
conn.connect(ip_server)
conn.createDirectory(shared_folder, sub_directory)
file_obj = open(local_path_file,'rb')
conn.storeFile(shared_folder, sub_directory+"/"+filename, file_obj)
file_obj.close()
```

in my case *sub_directory* is a whole path, thus I need to create each folder one by one (*createDirectory* works only this way) and everytime I need to check if the directory does not already exists because otherwise createDirectory raise an exception.

I hope my solution could be useful for others.

If anybody find a better solution, please answer...

Comment: This could be useful.. !!

Comment: With current state of pysmb that's the best you can do. An os.makedirs() version on the samba share would be nice to have.